# Purpose of validation set in model.fit?

Tags: time-series, validation

What is the purpose of the validation set in `model.fit(…)`?

Does this touch the concept of cross validation at all? Afaik cross validation is done in an "outside" loop, with the purpose of model selection considering theoretical concepts around bias and variance. However this validation set is "inside" the loop. I see that it is extremely useful as a hook for early stopping, which is used for regularization and efficiency.

Now to me (a beginner in machine learning) this looks unrelated. Is this just unfortunately misleading, or are they related?

How is it used? The validation set is used to calculate the validation loss and validation accuracy. But this is not done on every batch right. The calculation is done at the end on each epoch, right?

I read that time series have to be split and used carefully to not introduce a lookahead bias. I read that state of the art time series split is a blocked split, which look like this …

[image]

but I dont get the point in the test set (they mean validation set I guess).

Comment: Perhaps it would more helpful if you could tell us which `model.fit(...)` (e.g. which language, package etc.) you were referring to?

Comment: [tf.keras.Sequential.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit)